# lm function for a dataframe with arbitrary number of columns

Tags: r, lm

I am trying to program a function that applies to a data frame with an arbitrary number of columns. One part of the function involves the lm command and I am experiencing a complication. For this example, I'll use the following data:

```
x1 <- runif(100)
x2 <- runif(100)

z1 <- runif(100)
z2 <- runif(100)

y <- 0.2 + 0.7*x1 + 0.7*x2 + 0.4*z1 + 0.4*z2 + 0.8*z1*z2 + 0.8*z1^2 + 0.8*z2^2 + rnorm(100,0,.2) 

df <- data.frame(y,x1,x2,z1,z2)
```

The function is programmed to record how many x's and how many z's have been provided by the user, and it is always the case that the x's will appear in the data frame after the single y variable and before the z variables. So in this case there are 2 x's and 2 z's, and of course 1 y in the first column of the data frame. The function records the number of x's and z's as the variables n.x and n.z

```
n.x <- 2
n.z <- 2
```

I would like to include a regression of y on the x's and on a second order polynomial in the z's, but it has to be flexible in regard to the number of x's and z's that are provided by the user.

I know that if I was able to observe df directly, then I could simply use

```
linear.model <- lm(y ~ cbind(x1,x2) + poly(cbind(z1,z2),degree=2),data=df)
```

But in some cases there could be more or fewer x's and/or z's. I tried the following, knowing that it was unlikely to work:

```
linear.model <- lm(df$y ~ cbind(df[,2:(n.x+1)]) + poly(cbind(df[,(n.x+2):(n.x+n.z+1)]),degree=2))
```

and of course it didn't work. The key to this problem is that it has to use the n.x and n.z variables in lm to indicate where in the data frame the x's and z's are located.

Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create formula in a string from data frame names and
convert it with `as.formula`:

```
xs <- paste(names(df)[2:(1 + n.x)], collapse = ", ")
zs <- paste(names(df)[(2 + n.x):(1 + n.x + n.z)], collapse = ", ")

s_formula <- sprintf("y ~ cbind(%s) + poly(cbind(%s),degree=2)", xs, zs)

linear.model <- lm(as.formula(s_formula), data=df)
```

Comment: Thanks a million! This works nicely. I wish I could upvote you but my reputation still hasn't gotten to 15 yet.

Comment: Does this give the same result as the manual formula in the question? It doesn't for me.

Comment: @jlhoward I think the `rnorm(100,0,.2)` part at the end of `y` expression makes it a bit non-reproducible. I checked it without re-assigning df.

Comment: OK. Your using orthogonal polynomials this way.

Comment: @jlhoward  You're right, the estimated coefficients are quite different from the ones that appear in the formula for y. This is indeed confusing.

Comment: @Larry I get more accurate coefficients with 1000 observations instead of 100.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option. Code is more convoluted, but the end result is easier to interpret, I think.

```
cn <- colnames(df)
zz <- cn[grepl("^z",cn)]
xx <- cn[grepl("^x",cn)]
form <- paste0("y~",
               paste(paste(paste(xx,collapse="+")),
                     paste(zz,collapse="*"),
                     paste(paste0("I(",zz,"^2)"),collapse="+"), 
                     sep="+"))
form
# [1] "y~x1+x2+z1*z2+I(z1^2)+I(z2^2)
fit <- lm(as.formula(form),df)
coef(summary(fit))
#               Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) 0.20295008 0.11381558 1.78314847 7.786013e-02
# x1          0.68572092 0.08322408 8.23945324 1.141453e-12
# x2          0.70859080 0.07803392 9.08054860 1.964402e-14
# z1          0.74963604 0.32518472 2.30526218 2.340025e-02
# z2          0.01230116 0.34891211 0.03525577 9.719522e-01
# I(z1^2)     0.50320062 0.31074776 1.61932181 1.088012e-01
# I(z2^2)     1.13595678 0.30034582 3.78216276 2.762723e-04
# z1:z2       0.86561996 0.28552946 3.03163095 3.159388e-03
```

Note that in the formula argument for `lm(...)` the `*` operator produces all linear and cross terms, so, e.g., `z1*z2*z3` will produce all terms `z1 + z2  + z3 + z1:z2 + z1:z3 + z2:z3`, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answers. I will be sure to return and upvote you as soon as my reputation reaches 15.